# infinite many multiples of a polynomial in $\mathbb F_q[T]$

Tags: finite-fields

Let $P$ be an irreducible polynomial of $\mathbb F_q[T]$, $(u_n)_n$ be an infinite sequence of distinct elements of $\mathbb N_0$. Does there exist infinitely many multiples of $P$ in $\mathrm{Vect}_{\mathbb F_q}(T^{u_n}\mid n\in\mathbb N_0)$?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: to be clear, you mean the vector space spanned by the $T^{u_n}$?

Comment: yes, I meant that.

Comment: What's the motivation for this question?

Comment: I try to build a sequence of elements with small $P$-adic norm in this vector space.

Answer (score 7):

Sure.  Pick a root $\gamma$ of $P$ lying in some field extension $\mathbb{F_{q'}}$. We have a $\mathbb{F}_q$-linear map from this space of polynomials to $\mathbb{F_{q'}}$ given by evaluating a polynomial at $\gamma$.  This is going from an infinite dimensional space to a finite one, so it has a big kernel.